# Prevent installation of League of Legends Only

Tags: windows-10, installation, asus-laptop

I have a little brother who has become addicted to League of legends, and he keeps ruining his laptop by trying to download some kind of shady tools. Because of these tools, he is constantly exposed to viruses that usually end up with constant blue screens, missing drivers and ruined hardware

I want to add in some kind of prevention that will not allow him to ever install/play/interact with league of legends without my permission, whilst still allowing him to install other games and other applications without my permission/authorization.

Comment: From a social engineering standpoint the way to prevent this behaviour is to stop enabling it. Don't pay to repair it, tell him that he has to pay back the previous "loans" by doing chores, mowing lawns or selling lemonade. If he destroys the laptop by running shady virus laden tools then enable parental controls as described by harrymc below. If he circumvents that then tell him that you are going to have to lock the machine down further. Install [Deep Freeze](http://www.faronics.com/en-uk/products/deep-freeze/standard/) to wipe changes after a reboot, or just install Linux or take it away.

Comment: If his actions are the direct cause of problems then you need to let him know that there are consequences, not that someone is always going to be there to bail him out. Sometimes "tough love" is all you can fall back on.

Comment: Please accept an answer

Answer (score 2):

What you are asking for is a feature in Windows 10 called Parental Controls.

With Parental Controls, you can set up a user account for a child and
limit basically every aspect of his work :
programs they can run, websites they can visit,
how much time they can spend on the computer each day,
and you can also get detailed reports on their activity.

For more information see :

- [How to Add and Monitor a Child’s Account in Windows 10](https://www.howtogeek.com/225323/how-to-add-and-monitor-a-childs-account-in-windows-10/)
- [How to Use the Parental Controls in Windows 10](https://www.laptopmag.com/articles/parental-controls-windows-10)

Comment: Parental Controls is fine if you don't mind being tied to a Microsoft account. It doesn't support local accounts on the computer, though.