# How to prevent children from playing games on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, parental-controls

I'm looking for a method to lock my children out of using games on my win10 PC. I found some interested topics here about limiting bandwidth and other ones but I don't think any of these may fit my needs.

If I was able to lock DirectX, that would be an ideal solution, since all of their games use DirectX. Is it possible somehow to prevent DX from running while I'm out of home then re-enable it when I want?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prevent installation of League of Legends Only](https://superuser.com/questions/1238411/prevent-installation-of-league-of-legends-only)

Comment: Only way to block *all* gaming, many which don't use DirectX: lock the PC -- password protect or lock it in a cabinet.

Comment: just try to use the children account under family to limit children to run game.

Answer (score 5):

One solution is to create non-administrator account with the child's name and set up Parental Controls in Settings.  See [how to set parental controls for Windows 10](https://www.netnanny.com/blog/how-to-set-parental-controls-for-windows-10/).  You can block specific installed apps and websites.

Be aware that they can still visit websites that you don't know about and play games there.

Be aware of what icons are left on the Desktop and visible in the Start menu - it's not a friendly move to taunt them with things they're not allowed to have.

I don't suggest making changes to DirectX, given that you want to use it yourself.

EDIT : Of course, you would need to password-protect the admin account.